# Difference between "<>some" and "not in"

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I was reading the books fundamentals of database systems and in the topic nested subqueries(set comparison) it was written that `some` and `in` are identical whereas `<>some` and `not in` are not.
According to me `<>some` means "not at least one" and `not in` means "not in the set"...so I think they should mean the same.

Comment: These are not similar at all.  Perhaps you mean `<> all`?

Answer (score 8):

They are not the same!

`<>SOME` means: `not = a` **or** `not = b` **or** `not = c`...

`NOT IN` means: `not = a` **and** `not = b` **and** `not = c`...

Hope this will be more clear for you now.

For example:

```
SELECT CustomerID
FROM Sales.Customer
WHERE TerritoryID <> ANY
    (SELECT TerritoryID
    FROM Sales.SalesPerson);
```

This query return every single *CustomerID* with the exception of those for wich the `TerritoryID is NULL`.

While if you use `NOT IN` the query will return nothing.

Comment: And could you explain them why is some and in equivalent in set comparison?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I mean some and in mean the same in set comparison but <>some and not in are different...could you give an example showing this...

Comment: By the same logic some should mean a or b ....and in should mean a and b...so they should mean different

Comment: @ubuntu_noob `IN` means that every single value must be in the set. `SOME` or `ANY` means that at least one or more value must be in the set.

`NOT IN` and `<> SOME` are similar. `<> SOME` will returns `NULL` value while `NOT IN` will returns nothing

Comment: @ubuntu_noob if my answer satisfies you, please mark it ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179554/discussion-between-ubuntu-noob-and-simo).

Comment: @ubuntu_noob to [mark the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) just follow these simple steps

Answer (score 2):

<> only apply to 1 value, while "not in" apply to 1 or more values, e.g.

```
1. WHERE id <> '123'
2. WHERE id NOT IN ('123') --same as case 1
3. WHERE id NOT IN ('123', '456')
```

Comment: But then by the same logic some and in should also be different right?...but they are the same

Comment: this is not the answer to the question